# Postgres to Oracle connection

Tags: postgresql, oracle-fdw

How to maintain Postgres to Oracle data synchronized?

Currently we are trying to mimic the Oracle to Oracle database link but with Oracle to Postgres. I know that we can add FDW wrappers to connect but the latency is huge.

I have also checked AWS DMS process but it has lot of data type issues when data load and synchronization from Oracle to Postgres happens.

Can someone tell a better way?

Comment: If you can live with the data on the Postgres side to be a bit out of data or if the Oracle table is not updated very often, you can create a materialized view in Postgres based on the foreign table.

Comment: The issue is the Postgres instance is in AWS aurora. It is not allowed FDW to connect to oracle. So we created a Postgres instance in a Linux box where we instanced the FDW and bypass the connect but there is a huge latency. Replicating data is totally fine but we want the data to be in sync from oracle...can u suggest something more efficient?